How to execute epm automate commands using excel vba/macros without calling batch script file
I want to execute epmautomate commands from vba. Can you help me in writing it in macros so that when i execute the macro all the epm automate commands and should run and login
call epmautomate login username password https://epm-test-domain.epm.oraclecloud.com/HyperionPlanning/

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

We're not a script-writing service. Please have a read of https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

possibly using a windows shell command.
